# I am trying to insert data from a form using a servlet and bean file but when i try to insert the data i get - Driver does not support this function

Tags: sql, ms-access, servlets, javabeans, prepared-statement

I am using Access and Prepared Statement, the code below is my insertData Method:

```
public static Bean insertData(String name, int age, String date, boolean hero, boolean villian) {
....
sql = "insert into hv(name, age, firstApperance, hero, villian) values (?,?,?,?,?)";
PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
ps.setString(1, name);
ps.setInt(2, age);
ps.setString(3, date);
ps.setBoolean(4, hero);
ps.setBoolean(5, villian);          
ps.executeUpdate (sql);         
......
```

the first couple of error lines are:

```
Driver does not support this function
at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(Unknown Source)
at org.enterprise.Bean.insertData(Bean.java:59)
at org.enterprise.InsertData.doPost(InsertData.java:49)
```

i am just confused as to what the problem is beacuse i have checked if their is data in the variables name, age, date, hero, villian; And their is they were requested in my servlet and forwarded to this bean.

```
String name = request.getParameter("nameIn");
String ageInState = request.getParameter("ageIn");
....
```

and sent to bean class using:

```
bean = Bean.insertData(name, age, date, hero, villian);
```

Answer (score 1):

Why are you calling ps.executeUpdate(sql) when you've already put the SQL into the prepared statement at the top?

ps.executeUpdate() would probably work.

Check out http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html for reference.

Comment: dude sorry for the reply had even more problems... just to let you know that was the problem... i don't have enough rep to vote up.. so everyone else VOTE UP..lol Thanks bro